# Extracting objects from json objects against matching subfields using presto

Tags: sql, aws-glue, amazon-athena, presto, aws-glue-data-catalog

I have data that's been crawled through using AWS Glue and I'm querying using Athena, ie Presto. The data is originally JSON.

The data I'm interested in looks something like the following:

```
{ ...
  [ ...
    { 'items' : [
      {
        'label' : 'label-a',
        'description' : 'description-a'
      },
      {
        'label' : 'label-b',
        'description' : 'description-b'
      },
      ...]
...}
```

Thanks to Glue, 'items' is already represented as an array of objects.

What is the best method for me to query this in order to get the output of 'description' given a specific 'label'?
eg get the description for all items where label is 'label-a'

Comment: You have to flatten your data out ( https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/flattening-arrays.html ) and then filter out the rows you want, with something like `WHERE items.label = 'label-a'`.  Probably using `json_extract()` to get the `items` array out of the overall json object, to be passed in to `flatten` ( https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/extracting-data-from-JSON.html ).  But I don't have an Athena instance to write a full answer including the full query for you (which is why I'm only commenting).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a column `items` which is an array of objects, you can do:

```
select x.description from mytable cross join unnest(items) t(x)
where x.label='label-a'
```

Explanation: the unnest will "unroll" the array and represent it as a table `t` with a column `x` (your object). Each element in your array is a row in table `t`. The cross join will append to the current row the object `x` as a column, for all entries in the array `items` for the given row. Then you simply add your condition on the value of the label as `x.label = ...`.

See the docs on `unnest` here: https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest